# Make grid map from spatial data

Tags: r, maps, spatial, r-sf

I have spatial coordinates in a data frame where each row (Longitude, Latitude) corresponds to the occurrence of an event I am following. I tried to map these data but instead of using points, I want to create a grid with cells of a resolution of 5 nautical miles (~ 0.083333) and count the number of occurrences of the event is each cell and plot it.

This is the code I came to write with the help of some resources. But it doesn't look the way I expected it to be. Can you figure out what's I'm doing wrong? I attached the raw positions and the resulting map I get.
Here is the link to the [data](https://github.com/abenmhamed/data/blob/main/Events.csv).

```
re_pi = read.csv(file = "~/Desktop/Events.csv")

gridx <- seq(from=-19,to=-10,by=0.083333)
gridy <- seq(from=20,to=29,by=0.083333)
xcell <- unlist(lapply(re_pi$LON,function(x) min(which(gridx>x))))
ycell <- unlist(lapply(re_pi$LAT,function(y) min(which(gridy>y))))
re_pi$cell <- (length(gridx) - 1) * ycell + xcell

rr = re_pi %>%
  group_by(cell)%>%
  summarise(Lat = mean(LAT),Lon = mean(LON),Freq = length(cell))

my_theme <- theme_bw() + theme(panel.ontop=TRUE, panel.background=element_blank())
my_cols <- scale_color_distiller(palette='Spectral')
my_fill <- scale_fill_distiller(palette='Spectral')

ggplot(rr, aes(y=Lat, x=Lon, fill=Effort)) + geom_tile(width=1.2, height=1.2) +
  borders('world', xlim=range(rr$Lon), ylim=range(rr$Lat), colour='black') + my_theme + my_fill +
  coord_quickmap(xlim=range(rr$Lon), ylim=range(rr$Lat))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your shapefile as well?

Comment: I don't have a shapefile and I didn't use a shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice dataset, assume these are fishing vessel VMS data. Here may be one way to achieve your objective, heavily reliant on the tidyverse and by-passing raster and shapes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mapdata) # higher resolution maps
# poor man's gridding function
grade <- function (x, dx) {
  if (dx > 1)
    warning("Not tested for grids larger than one")
  brks <- seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), dx)
  ints <- findInterval(x, brks, all.inside = TRUE)
  x <- (brks[ints] + brks[ints + 1])/2
  return(x)
}
d <-
  read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abenmhamed/data/main/Events.csv") %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  # make a grid 0.01 x 0.01 longitude / latitude
  mutate(lon = grade(lon, 0.01),
         lat = grade(lat, 0.01)) %>%
  group_by(lon, lat) %>%
  count() %>%
  # not much happening south of 21 and north of 26
  filter(between(lat, 21, 26.25))
d %>%
  ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_tile(aes(lon, lat, fill = n)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1) +
  # only data within the data-bounds
  borders(database = "worldHires",
          xlim = range(d$lon), ylim = range(d$lat),
          fill = "grey") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = "Effort") +
  # limit plot
  coord_quickmap(xlim = range(d$lon), ylim = range(d$lat)) +
  # legends within plot
  theme(legend.position = c(0.77, 0.26))
```

[image]

Comment: That's right, it's VMS data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: for visuals you may want to try square-rooting the effort, draws out more intricacies. i.e.:geom_tile(aes(lon, lat, fill = sqrt(n)))

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt using the sf package. First I imported your data and converted it to an sf object. Then, I created another sf object which includes the grids. I used the raster package and the sf package in order to create the grids. Once I had the two sf object, I counted how many data points exist in each grid and added the results as a new column in `foo`. Finally, I drew a graphic.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(viridis)

# Import the data and convert it to an sf object
mydata <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abenmhamed/data/main/Events.csv") %>%
          st_as_sf(coords = c("LON", "LAT"), 
                   crs = 4326, agr = "constant")

# Create an sf object for the grid
gridx <- seq(from = -19,to = -10, by = 0.083333)
gridy <- seq(from = 20,to = 29, by = 0.083333)


foo <- raster(xmn = -19, xmx = -10,
              ymn = 20, ymx = 29,
              nrows = length(gridx),
              ncols = length(gridy)) %>% 
       rasterToPolygons() %>% 
       st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>% 
       mutate(group = 1:(length(gridx)*length(gridy))) %>% 
       st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")


# Now count how many data points exist in each grid
mutate(foo,
       count = lengths(st_intersects(x = foo,  y = mydata))) -> foo

# Draw a graphic
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = foo, aes(fill = count)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "D") -> g
```

[image]

Comment: that is great. Is there a way to crop it with nearest land map (Morocco in this case)

Comment: @AbdelouahedBENMHAMED As long as you have a shapefile, I am sure you can do it. If you search on SO or gis exchange, you can find a way to do it.

Comment: Can you help me adding please as I am not fluent with using maps. I have attached the shape file to the same repository as the data. https://github.com/abenmhamed/data

Comment: @AbdelouahedBENMHAMED I wish you had that shapefile from the beginning. I am about go out to do my own things. So I am afraid that I cannot help you. I recommend you to check `st_make_grid()`. If you use the shapefile, I think making grids is much easier, I suppose.

Comment: Well, thank you so much. that was very helpful. I thought that the shapefile you were asking for is the grid shapefile. that's why I didn't attached it first. Thanks